# for loop in if statement javascript not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

The idea behind this code is pretty simply when some one click on the button, insert the one false value if it does not exist, to do that, i created the for loop, which check how many false value exist, and if they are less than one than insert the false value else do nothing

here is the the code

```
addNote(index){
    const order = this.state.order
    var j =0;
    const note=order[index].note
    for(var i =0; i<note.length; i++){
        if(note[i].display===false){j++;}
        if(j==0){note[note.length]={display:false}}
        console.log(j)
    }
    console.log(note)
    this.setState({order:this.state.order}) 
}
```

if you see the console log result, it is increasing the value for j for each click, than why my if statement is working for each click, it should only work if the value for j is zero, i am talking about this line `if(j==0){note[note.length]={display:false}}`

here is the array before any click

```
0:Object
        display:true
        note:"jhj"
```

the array after second click

```
0:Object
        display:true
        note:"jhj"
    1:Object
        display:false
```

the array after second click

```
 0:Object
    display:true
    note:"jhj"
1:Object
    display:false
2:Object
    display:false
```

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Is there something missing from it?

Comment: *"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"* There is a second `}` after the first `if` statement. Where should this belong to? Should it close the loop body? Is the second `if` statement supposed to be inside or outside the loop? If both `if` statements are inside the loop, the behavior is easily explained: In the first iteration `j` will always be `0`. Hence `if (j==0)` is `true` and a new object is added to the array. In other words, you are not looking at *all* entries before you decide to add an entry. You are only looking at the first entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both `if` statements are inside the loop, then you will add a new entry to the array *every time* `addNote` is called. That's because `j` is always `0` in the first iteration of the loop and because `note[0].display` is `true`, it stays `0`. 
Then of course `if (j==0)` is `true`, adding a new element to the array.
In other words, you are deciding whether or not to add a new entry by looking at each element individually, not together.

> if they are less than one than insert the false value else do nothing

That's not what your code is doing. Your code inserts a new value if *any* entry has `display: true`. Since the first element has that, your code always adds a new entry.

The following code would do what you want (instead of the loop):

```
if (!note.some(item => item.display === false)) {
  note.push({display:false});
}
```

Which translates to "if there is not an element with `display === false` add a new element.